# Нужно передавать в скрипт значение, но onload с div не работает

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Нужно передавать в скрипт значение, но `onload` с `div` не работает.

```
<div onload="myfunc(this)" data-passed-perc="@passed_perc"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**div** не поддерживает событие **onload**

Ты можешь сделать например так:

```
<div id="sampleId" data-passed-perc="@passed_perc"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
   myfunc("sampleId");
</script>
```

А в самой функции myfunc:

```
function myfunc(id){
    var element = document.getElementById(id);
    var passedPerc = element.getAttribute("data-passed-perc");
    ...
   }
```

jquery:

```
<div id="sampleId" data-passed-perc="@passed_perc"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
   myfunc("#sampleId");
</script>
```

---

```
function myfunc(id){
    var element = $(id);
    var passedPerc = element.attr("data-passed-perc");
    ...
}
```

Если же ты хочешь передать переменную @passed_perc, то нет смысла создавать div:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    myfunc("@passed_perc");
</script>
```

### **Дополнение:**

Нашел более лучшее решение для jquery https://stackoverflow.com/a/35809187/4555549